# Term for puffed up feathers

Tags: adjectives

Is there any single-worded term that describes a bird with puffed up feathers?

Comment: I believe that "fluff-up" in a feather context is appropriate.

Comment: Please include a sentence showing how the word is to be used. Or are only adjectives acceptable? There may be some other work-arounds.

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, only adjectives. E.G. "ruffled" but per lambie, that's just rippling.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your use of *any single-worded term*. Yes, a term *can* consist of a single word—but why not just say *a single word*?

Comment: Oops @Jason Bassford. I missed that.

Comment: Why would you think there could be a word for it?  Would you think that there could be single words to describe a man with a crew-cut, or a woman wearing high heels, or a vehicle with tinted windows?  Language does not work that way.  We extend the power of language by partnering  the words we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an adjective, but I think you are looking for rouse, roused, or rousing. Etymology:
Verb: Middle English, to shake the feathers

Edit: From [TFD]

> [1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rouse) 5. (Falconry) (intr) falconry (of hawks) to ruffle the feathers
> and cause them to stand briefly on end (a sign of contentment)

Comment: Consider including a link to a formal definition of the word

Answer (score 1):

**ruffle**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruffle+feathers)

3. To erect (the feathers). Used of birds.

Comment: When a bird ruffles its feathers, it's like rippling water. It is not making the feathers stand  up and stay in that position.

Comment: @lambie That's not what the dictionary definition says. And [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruffle) expands on TFD: "to erect in or like a ruff : to cause to rise or bristle." Where do you get this "rippling water" idea from? [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ruffle) does give a different sense: "Disturb the smoothness or tranquillity of. ‘the evening breeze ruffled the surface of the pond in the yard’ But it's a *different* sense, and not bird related . . .

Answer (score 1):

According to an article titled "[How do birds keep warm?](https://toughlittlebirds.com/2012/12/26/how-do-birds-keep-warm/)" on the Tough Little Birds website, the term for feather fluffing or puffing is *ptiloerection*:

> **Feathers:** There is a reason why we fill our best coats with goose down. Feathers are fantastic insulation. Downy feathers trap tiny pockets of air next to the bird, allowing the bird to warm those pockets of air and hold that warm air around itself, preventing cold air from touching its skin. The more air trapped, the warmer the bird. Birds fluff up (the technical term for fluffing up is “**ptiloerection**”) in the cold to trap as much air in their feathers as possible.

[Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piloerection), however, suggests that the correct spelling of the term is **piloerection**:

> **piloerection** *noun* (1930) erection or bristling of hairs due to the involuntary contraction of small muscles at the base of hair follicles that occurs as a reflexive response of the sympathetic nervous system especially to cold, shock, or fright

What this definition describes is, of course, the condition familiarly known as *goose bumps*, *goose flesh*, *chicken skin*, etc.

The prefix *pilo-* derives from Latin *pilus* (hair). Nevertheless, the connection to birds is strong—and "[Do Birds Get Goose Bumps?](https://ornithology.com/do-birds-get-goose-bumps/)" on the Ornithology: The Science of Birds website asserts that fluffing is indeed a feathery form of piloerection:

> So the papillae function to form feathers, but at their base are small muscles which contract to move the papillae and thus the feathers. If you kept a parakeet at some time in your life, you are familiar with their fluffing up their feathers. They might do it in response to a perceived threat such as a dog or cat in the house, another parakeet, or just a general disturbance. The bird will also fluff up when it is ill, to avoid losing body heat. And that’s what you see in the wild most– birds sitting on a branch in the winter, appearing to be twice their normal size. They **piloerect** their feathers to produce air spaces between them for insulation.